# How to ask users to always use the 'precise location' option?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location

[image]

Hello.
I'm making an app that organizes the user's movement records when hiking.
So I want to encourage users to use the `Precise Location` option all the time.

However, I saw a lot of pop-ups asking me to set location permissions on other apps, but I couldn't find a pop-up or UX asking me to turn on the `Precise Location` that was turned off. Is it against `Apple's policy` to ask for this?

If you don't violate it, I'd like to know how other apps ask users to turn on their permissions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager)'s [CLAccuracyAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/claccuracyauthorization/) property to determine whether the user has full/reduced accuracy. Note that this is available from iOS 14 / macOS 11.

```swift
switch locationManager.accuracyAuthorization {
    case .fullAccuracy:
        // TODO: handle fullAccuracy
    case .reducedAccuracy:
        // TODO: handle reducedAccuracy - request temporary full accuracy
    @unknown default:
        // TODO: handle default
}
```

If the result is `.reducedAccuracy`, you can use [requestTemporaryFullAccuracyAuthorization(withPurposeKey:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3600217-requesttemporaryfullaccuracyauth) to request temporary access to `.fullAccuracy`.

Don't forget to fill in [NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationtemporaryusagedescriptiondictionary) and use appropriate key in the function above.

It would look something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can kindly ask users to enable precise location by presenting an `UIAlertController` which will contain description why you need it for, and action to navigate to app settings. When they press the action you will navigate to app settings likewise:

```
func navigateToSystemSettings() {
    if let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)  {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Presenting simple UIAlert:

```
func presentAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Precise location", message: "Please enable precise location by tapping location -> precise location", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Navigate to settings", style: .default) { _ in
        self.navigateToSystemSettings()
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Also prior to displaying `UIAlertController` it would be nice to present some screenshot with some arrow pointing to "precise location" switch in settings, so it would be more clear what the user should do.

**P.S.**
This `navigateToSystemSettings()` function should open your App settings. If it only opens the plain "Settings" instead, fix the issue by uploading app to testflight so that it appears among another apps that are presented on bottom of "Settings" app.